# How to create a simple route in Golang?

Tags: go

I'm a new member and I wanted to create an API without chatGPT

I tried:

```
func route(w http.RequestWrite, r *http.Response) {
    w Write.byte[]("Hello world")
 }
```

I'm trying to study without looking at chatGPT and it's been tough, I never had a teacher and it's not easy.

I searched for a question like mine on StackOverflow and didn't find it either

Comment: Are you getting an error, what about this is not working?

Comment: I fixed it, but I realized it's a server not a router. How to create a route?

Comment: What have you tried? The [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#hdr-Servers) are pretty good and include a "Hello X" example; you may also find [the wiki](https://go.dev/doc/articles/wiki/) useful, and there are [other resources](https://go.dev/solutions/webdev) available too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is pass your function to the http.HandleFunc. Note that your types were incorrect so I made some modifications to it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello world")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello-world", route)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil)
}
```